# Getting determinant of matrix with unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Im trying to get the determinant of 
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 3 & 2x & -1 \\ 
2 & x+3  & 2x  & -1 \\ 
2 -x & 3  &3x  &0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 2x+2 &x-1 
\end{vmatrix}

And they show that they go from the above matrix to this:

\begin{vmatrix}
2(x+1) & 3 & 2x  & -1 \\ 
2(x+1) & x+3 & 2x & -1\\ 
2(x+1) & 3 & 3x & 0 \\ 
2(x+1) & 3 & 2x+2  & x-1 
\end{vmatrix}

I do not quite follow how these two steps are connected.

Comment: Add the third column to the first column.

Comment: By the gods im slow today. Thanks!